# How to get multiple values from a dictionary in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I find and print the name and age of `'id' == 52`? Is using a `for` loop the only way?

```
name_list = [
    {'id': 11, 'name': 'John', 'Age': 22},
    {'id': 52, 'name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25},
    {'id': 9, 'name': 'Carl', 'Age': 55 }
]
```

Comment: `for rec in name_list:
  if rec['id'] == 52: print(f"Name: {rec['name']} Age: {rec['Age']}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a standard loop through a list.

```
for i in name_list:
    if i['id'] == 52:
        print(i['name'])
        print(i['Age'])
```

Comment: @tonypdmtr good catch. I just wasn't paying attention. Answer has been edited.

Comment: PEP8, try this:
`if not i['id'] == 52:
    continue
....`

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I can think of is to use a loop in list comprehension form:

```
In [1]: [x for x in name_list if x['id'] == 52]
Out[1]: [{'id': 52, 'name': 'Mary', 'Age': 25}]
```